# MySQL performance boost after create & drop index

Tags: mysql, sql, caching, indices

I have a large MySQL, MyISAM table of around 4 million rows running in a core 2 duo, 8G RAM laptop.

This table has 30 columns including varchar, decimal and int types.

I have an index on a varchar(16). Let's call this column: "indexed_varchar_column".

My query is

```
SELECT 9 columns FROM the_table WHERE indexed_varchar_column = 'something';
```

It always returns around 5000 rows for every 'something' I query against.

An EXPLAIN to the query returns this:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys                                      | key                                        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | the_table   | ref  | many indexes including indexed_varchar_column      | another_index NOT: indexed_varchar_column! | 19      | const | 5247 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

First thing is I'm not sure is why another_index is chosen. In fact it chooses an index which is a composite index of indexed_varchar_column and another 2 columns (which form part of the selected ones). Perhaps this makes sense since it may make things a bit faster for not having to read 2 of the columns in the query. The real QUESTION is the **following one**:

The query takes 5 seconds for every 'something' I match. On the 2nd time I query against 'something' it takes 0.15 secs (I guess because the query is being cached). When I run another query against 'something_new' it takes again 5 seconds. So, it is consistent.

THE PROBLEM IS: I discovered that creating an index (another composite index including my indexed_varchar_column) and dropping it again produces that all further queries against new 'something_other' take only 0.15 secs. Please note that 1) I create an index 2) drop it again. So everything is in the same state.

I guess all the operations needed for building and dropping indices make the SQL engine to cache something that is then reused. When I run EXPLAIN on a query after all this I get exactly the same as before.

How can I proceed to understand what is cached in the create-drop index procedure so that I can cache it without manipulating indices?

**UPDATE:**

Following a comment from Marc B that suggested that when mySQL creates an index it internally does a SELECT... I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

It took 30 secs and returned 4 million rows. The good thing is that all further queries are very fast again (until I reboot the system). Please note that after rebooting the queries are slow again. I guess this is because mySQL is using some sort of OS caching.

Any idea? How can I explicitly cache the table I guess?

**UPDATE 2:**
Perhaps I should have mentioned that this table may be severely fragmented. It's 4 million rows but I remove lots of old fields regularly. I also add new ones. Since I had large gaps in IDs (for the rows deleted) every day I drop the primary index (ID) and create it again with consecutive numbers. The table may be then very fragmented and therefore IO must be an issue... Not sure what to do.

Comment: building an index internally does basically a 'select fields,in,index from ...' to get the data needed to build the index, so the data would be cached for you simply by having built the index, even though you yourself haven't run any selects.

Comment: Thanks Marc B. This gave me an idea. I run a crazy "SELECT * FROM my_table" on the 4 million rows. I did this on the console and discarded all results. I took a while. The same time it takes to create an index, approx. All further queries are superfast. Is it there any other elegant way achieve the same effect? I'll update the question with this finding.

Comment: So you have two indexes that include `indexed_varchar_column`: one is the composite index on `{indexed_varchar_column, other_column1, other_column2}`. How does the other index look like? Is it composite and what is the order of columns in it?

Comment: Branko, you can forget about the indices. A simple SELECT * FROM my_table caches everything. I believe I have an IO bottleneck on the hardisk (there are too many columns I need to query and a covering index would be too big). The IO bottleneck is alleviated when I run a SELECT *. I guess I'd need to cache the table explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your help.

Finally I discovered (thanks to the hint of Marc B) that my table was severely fragmented after many INSERTs and DELETEs. I updated the question with this info some hours ago. There are two things that help:

1)

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ORDER BY indexed_varchar_column;
```

2) Running:

```
myisamchk --sort-records=4 my_table.MYI  (where 4 corresponds to my index)
```

I believe both commands are equivalent. Queries are fast even after a system reboot.
I've put this ALTER TABLE ORDER BY command on a cron that is run everyday. It takes 2 minutes but it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the order of the columns in your composite index.

You must use (at least) a left-associative sub-set of the columns in your query

If you have an index on foo,bar, and baz, that will *not* be usable as an index against bar or baz by themeselves. Only (foo), (foo,bar), and (foo,bar,baz).

`EXPLAIN` is your friend here. It will tell you which index, if any, is being used by a query.

*EDIT* Here's a postgres explain of a simple left join query for comparison.

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..16.97 rows=13 width=103)
    Join Filter: (pagesets.id = pages.pageset_id)
      ->  Index Scan using ix_pages_pageset_id on pages  (cost=0.00..8.51 rows=13 width=80)
              Index Cond: (pageset_id = 515)
      ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=23)
          ->  Index Scan using pagesets_pkey on pagesets  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=23)
                Index Cond: (id = 515)
```

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I undestood Tyler. I have multiple composite indices but there is one index for indexed_varchar_column. Then, this index is not used as mysql decides to use another one as I explained. The real question is at the bottom part of my post. I don't understand why creating and dropping an index makes all further queries more than 2000 times faster

Comment: Ok, I see where you've added more to the question now. Frankly, Mysql is _dumb_, *really* _dumb_. It's query planning is famously bad. If this sort of thing bothers you (and it should), PostgreSQL is a superior alternative. It's EXPLAIN out is a lot better too.

Answer (score 0):

How many indexes do you have that contain the indexed_varchar_column? Do you have a single index for just the indexed_varchar_column?

Have you tried:
`SELECT 9 columns FROM USE INDEX (name_of_index) the_table WHERE indexed_varchar_column = 'something';`?

Comment: Yes, I've done this. Results are the same. I guess mySQL chose another index that has other columns of the query. This is not the real problem. The problem is why do I get such a performance boost after creating and dropping an index. What has been cached? Regarding how many indices contain indexed_varchar_column: it's on 3 composite indices.

Comment: How about posting the actual, full, table and index declerations? Change the column names if you must, but stopping making us play psychic!

Comment: Tyler, the table is pretty big and I believe it would make the whole thing more confusing. I updated the question with another finding which definitely points to a caching issue.