# Reset performance of all queries in mysql 8

Tags: mysql, performance-testing, mysql-8.0

I am working with MySQL 8 for learning purposes. I created a covering index for a query that significantly increased its speed. Now I dropped that index and restarted my computer, but it seems like the query performance remained more or less the same.
Is there any way to reset the state of MySql 8.0, so that I can test again all my queries as if they are being run for the first time?

Comment: You can check if that index still exist by running `show index from table_name` it will return all the indexes on that table

Comment: I think your answer is here: [MySQL performance boost after create & drop index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354153/mysql-performance-boost-after-create-drop-index)

Comment: @Luuk thanks for the link. However, that question got an answer related to myisam, I am using Innodb...

Comment: Most question are looking for an answer on speeding up a query, not on reverting it to become slow again. But, for consolation, In you learning curve you will hit plenty of problems with slow queries 

Comment: How big is your table, and how fast is your query? Tests on small tables can be misleading.

Comment: @Solarflare I'd say it's a huge one, almost 7 GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn these OFF:

```
mysql> show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool%at%';
+-------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                       | Value |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON    |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
```

When they are ON, which might be the *default* for MySQL 8, the buffer_pool (InnoDB's main caching mechanism) is reloaded even after a reboot.

So, change your settings to have them off, then restart only `mysqld` to get MySQL into a "cold" state.

I take a different approach...  The important timing is what will happen in a "production" environment -- where the buffer_pool is actively used, not cleared.  So, I prefer to run a query twice and use the second timing.

Also, it is wise to keep the Query cache off.

More things for your learning exercise:

- Indexing: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql
- "Handler" counts:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts
- Slowlog:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog